# Rendering form partials - undefined method `to_key'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to render a form partial in a separate controller.

```
#app/views/users/my_transactions.html.erb
<%= render 'transactions/form', transaction: @transaction %>
```

Form page.

```
#app/views/transactions/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(transaction) do |f| %>
  <% if transaction.errors.any? %>
                ...
```

But cannot stop receiving this error:

> undefined method `to_key' for Transaction::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fc308301c18
>
> Did you mean?
> to_query 
> to_set
> to_ary

My controllers:

```
#app/controllers/transactions_controller.rb
def create
  @transaction = Transaction.new(transaction_params)
  @transaction.user = current_user
                   ...
```

and

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def my_transactions
  @transaction = current_user.transactions
  @user = current_user 
end
```

Thank you in advance!! I can't find any solution to this, and I've already read through a good chunk of documentation in hopes of resolving.

## Edit

Clearer view of render calls (with fix by @engineersmnky)

```
#app/views/users/my_transactions.html.erb
<h3>New Transaction</h3>
<%= render 'transactions/form', transaction: @user.transactions.build %>
<h3>Current Transactions</h3>
<%= render 'transactions/show' %>
```

Clear view of show partial

```
#app/views/transactions/_show.html.erb
<% @user.transactions.each do |transaction| %>
<tr>
  <td class="date"><%= transaction.created_at.strftime("%D") %></td>
  <td><%= transaction.amount %></td>
  <td class="convert-category"><%= transaction.category %></td>
  <td class="convert-sub-category"><%= transaction.sub_category %></td>
  <td><%= transaction.notes%></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in `UsersController`.

The `TransactionsController#create` method should be fine because you are only referencing a single `Transaction`. In `UsersController` you are referencing a Collection of `Transactions` for the `current_user` hence the error.

You should be able to just change this to

```
def my_transactions
  @transaction = current_user.transactions.build
  @user = current_user 
end
```

This way `@transaction` will be a single new `Transaction` associated with the `current_user` in both contexts.

Your other option is if you are showing all transactions and the ability to add a new one then leave the `UsersController` alone and change the render statement to:

```
#app/views/users/my_transactions.html.erb
<%= render 'transactions/form', transaction: @user.transactions.build %>
```

This will have the same effect on the form as the above but will leave your `@transaction` instance variable as a collection of `Transactions` for display purposes on that view.

Comment: Option 2 works when I rearrange my #app/views/users/my_transactions.html.erb to display the current transactions at the top via <% render 'transactions/show' %> but I want display render the new partial then the show partial. I know this has something to do with the instance variable processing of rendering the form before the show partial. For reference, _show.html.erb begins with <% @user.transactions.each do |transaction| %>

Comment: @jcxswc You comment is very unclear. If you want the show partial below the form just add `<%= render 'transactions/show' %>` after `<%= render 'transactions/form', transaction: @user.transactions.build %>` but I would have assumed that `TransactionsController#show` was meant to be a RESTful representation of a single transaction with a path like "/transactions/:id"

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. Via the _show.html.erb partial right below the _form.html.erb, I am displaying a full list of transactions. So, the user can add a transaction at the top of the webpage but can also view ALL of the transactions at the bottom. In the _show.html.erb my starting each loop is <% @user.transactions.each do |transaction| %>

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is happening at the `render` method:
Here you are passing the `@transaction` as if it's a single object, but is is a collection. You should use the collection option with `render`. Something like this:

```
# app/views/users/my_transactions.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'transactions/form', collection: @transactions %>
```

More at section 3.4.5 of Rails Guides (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Comment: `render` is not the problem. The error is `form_for(transaction)` because the local `transaction` being passed is a `CollectionProxy`  not a single instance of `Transaction`